# Does a MacBook Pro need a power adapter to work in the Bahamas?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation, magsafe

A classmate asked me if the US MacBook Pro adapters are usable in the Bahamas. It boils down to the type of electricity and outlets there, but being that I have no clue, I'm asking here.

Does a USA compatible MacBook Pro adapter require an adapter for the Bahamas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [these guys](http://www.adaptelec.com/index.php?main_page=document_general_info&products_id=254), anything that works in the US should work in the Bahamas.

> Voltage: 110-120 Volts (Same as U.S./Canada, most other areas are
>   220-240 Volts)
>
> Primary Socket Types: North American Non-Grounded , North American
>   Grounded

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need a power adapter. All you might need is round pin socket plug or a universal plug because US uses flat pins and many countries have a round pin.

I have used my MacBook in places like Mexico, India, and China without any power adapter where the AC voltage was 220V.